# How do I handle NaN values in the target ratio when running a Metropolis Hastings algorithm in R for a correlation parameter?

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to run a Metropolis Hastings algorithm on R for a correlation parameter (rho) which comes from N observations (x,y) with a bivariate normal distribution with mean (0,0) and covariance matrix ({1,rho},{rho,1}). Only the correlation term, rho, is of interest.

The posterior distribution (likelihood*prior) takes the below form:

```r
prod(1 / ((2 * pi * (1 - rho^2))^(1/2)) * (exp(-(x^2 - 2 * rho * x * y + 
     y^2) / (2 * (1 - rho^2))))*(1 / (1 - rho^2)^(3/2)))
```

Running the below code in R gives me a "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" error in the if statement in the metropolis function.

```r
#obtain dataset 
x <- data$device1
y <- data$device2

#defining target as a function, this is made from likelihood*priors
target <- function(rho){prod(1 / ((2 * pi * (1 - rho^2))^(1/2)) *
     (exp(-(x^2 - 2 * rho * x * y + y^2) / 
     (2 * (1 - rho^2))))*(1 / (1 - rho^2)^(3/2)))}

# as proposals we consider the uniform distribution 
# U(rho^(i-1)-k,rho^(i-1)+k)
metropolis <- function(rho) {
  rho2 <- runif(1, rho - 0.01, rho + 0.01)
  
  target_rho2 <- target(rho2)
  target_rho <- target(rho)
  
  if (runif(1) > target_rho2/target_rho) {
    rho2 <- rho
  }

  return(rho2)
}

N <- 10000
rho <- mat.or.vec(1, N)
rho[1] <- 0.1
count <- 1

for(n in 2:N){
  repeat{
    rho[n] <- metropolis(rho[n-1])
    count <- count + 1
    if(rho[n]!=rho[n-1]){break}
  }
}
```

I have identified that such error comes from the ratio of target_rho2/target_rho giving NaN values since there are instances where we get 0/0. I have tried altering the IF statement by adding conditions such as

```r
is.nan(target_rho2) || is.nan(target_rho) || runif(1) >   
    target_rho2/target_rho' or 'is.finite(target_rho2) && 
    is.finite(target_rho) && runif(1) > target_rho2/target_rho
```

but the error keeps popping up.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually a bad idea to calculate the ratio as `x/y`, because sometimes both `x` and `y` are so small that R sees the ratio as `0/0`. The better way is to calculate `logx - logy`. You just have to be careful to calculate `logx` and `logy` directly, not as `log(x)` and `log(y)`.

For example, change your `target()` function to this:

```
logtarget <- function(rho) 
  sum( - log(2*pi*(1 - rho^2)) - 
       (x^2 - 2 * rho * x * y + y^2) / 
       (2 * (1 - rho^2)) 
       - log((1 - rho^2)^(3/2))
```

and use the test

```
if (log(runif(1)) > logtarget_rho2/logtarget_rho)
```

You should check that I got the expression right for the log target, perhaps by comparing it to `log(target(rho))` for a few values.

Comment: Thank you for your above suggestion, I tried it out and it worked! :)

For future reference (just in case someone else encounters the same scenario), the logtarget function used was this: 

`logtarget <- function(rho){sum((-1/2) * log(2 * pi * (1 - rho^2)) - (x^2 - 2 * rho * x * y + y^2) / (2 * (1 - rho^2)) - (3/2) * log(1 - rho^2))}`